# Basic confusion about Banach fixed point theorem

Tags: analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Banach fixed point theorem says that if $T$ is a mapping and there is a $q \in [0,1)$ where
$|Tx - Ty| \leq q |x-y|$  for all $x,y$ then $T$ has a fixed point.

But if $T$ is a linear operator, then the $|Tx-Ty| \leq q|x-y|$ condition implies

$$|T(x-y)|\leq q|(x-y|,$$

which in turn implies $|Tz| \leq q|z|$ for any $z$ (since any vector $z$ can be represented as a difference of some pair of vectors $x$ and $y$).

But this seems to contradict $T$ having a fixed point, since if $Tz = z$, then $|Tz| = |z|\gt q|z|$ (unless $z=0$, but that would mean that only $0$ can be a fixed point).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Every linear mapping of the vector space to the same vector space has a fixed point (the origin). You don't need Banach's fixed point theorem for existence.

Also, Banach's theorem gives uniqueness if $q\in [0,1)$. However, the identity map has operator norm $1$, i.e $q\geq \|T\|=1$, which is clearly not in $[0,1)$, so the theorem cannot be applied, so you cannot deduce that there is a **unique** fixed point (also clearly for the identity map every point is fixed).

Comment: But if T is a linear contraction operator from V to V with ||T|| < 1, then Banach's theorem would apply (for uniqueness) and 0 would be the only fixed point. Is that correct?

Comment: @user9809 yes, that's correct (for example, on a Banach space $V$, the mapping $T:V\to V$, $T(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ is a contraction, and clearly has a unique fixed point, since $T(x)=x$ if and only if $\frac{x}{2}=x$, and hence $x=0$).